# Are different function pointers compatible with each other?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

Today I have learned that function pointers and data pointers are not the same and are therefore not compatible with each other ([Why are function pointers and data pointers incompatible in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12358843/1771055)). My question however is, are different function (non member) pointers compatible with each other (are implemented the same way).

In code:

```
typedef void(*FuncPtr0)();
typedef void(*FuncPtr1)(int);

FuncPtr0 p0;
FuncPtr1 p1;

p0 = reinterpret_cast<FuncPtr0>(p1);    // will this always work, if p1 really 
p0();                                   // points to a function of type FuncPtr0
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

n3376 5.2.10/6

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. The effect of calling
> a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition
> of the function is undefined. Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to
> T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems it was quite easy to find the answer to this question. May I ask you, how did you go about finding the citation in the standard?

Comment: @rozina simply look on paragraph, that talk about reinterpret_cast.

Comment: I googled and found out that the standard is not free, which explains why no google search result ever shows the standard only quotes here on stackoverflow :) Thanks again though!

Comment: @rozina google about standard drafts. They are free. My quote is from n3376 draft.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not compatible and will invoke *undefined behavior*. You will have unspecified results.

In fact you can cast them to each other, but you shouldn't call a function pointer which points to a non-compatible function signature.
For example, see [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32d0ea813ba992be) :

```
typedef void(*FuncPtr0)();

void p1f()      { std::cout << "ONE";        }
void p2f(int x) { std::cout << "TWO " << x ; }

int main()
{
    FuncPtr0 p0 = reinterpret_cast<FuncPtr0>(p2f);
    p0();
}
```

Output

```
TWO 1
```

The question is who set argument `x` to `1` ? It may run but the result is unspecified. In my system the result is something else (garbage) `TWO 39`.