# Function pointers with different return types

Tags: c++, c

Is this correct code?

```
class SomeClass;

SomeClass* createSomeClass(); // just returns new SomeClass
void* (*createFuncPtr)();

int main()
{
    createFuncPtr= (void* (*)()) &createSomeClass;
    SomeClass* instance = (SomeClass*)createFuncPtr();
}
```

The C standard says:

> 768 If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is
>   not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined.

In this case, are the function types compatible? Or am I forced to re-cast the function pointer before calling it if I want to avoid ant kind of trouble?

```
SomeClass* instance = ((SomeClass* (*)())createFuncPtr)();
```

Thanks!

Edit: yes, it contains C++ code but my question remains valid if it was C only, please leave the C tag.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just getting an answer to that specific question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C99 standard section 6.7.5.1, paragraph 2:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

In your case, the function pointers are not compatible, because the return values are not compatible. So, yes, you have to cast back before calling the pointed to function.

Comment: Thanks Filipe, it makes sense. But what are two _compatible types_ then? Do you have an example of compatible types where this function pointer cast would work?

Comment: @JeremyLaumon The bottom line is that `void` and `someClass` are not compatible types, because, well, they are different types. The rules for type compatibility are rather long, but you can look at section 6.2.7 in C99.

Answer (score -2):

You need to cast it back to the correct type, otherwise you will most likely corrupt your stack. See a more detailed and somewhat funny description here: [Old New Thing: A function pointer cast is a bug waiting to happen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx)

Edit: Since you need to cast it to the right type anyway you may as well just <s>use a void pointer</s> (Edit: does not work since a void pointer could have a smaller size, thanks to Filipe) instead of the wrong function pointer to store the pointer to avoid accidentally calling it wrong. Or use the correct function pointer type. Or an std::function object, depending on your goals.

Comment: @Filipe
Where does it say that and why should that not work? Crazy platforms with different sized pointers for functions and void pointers?

Comment: @nwp yes, that's a good example. The standard doesn't guarantee that void pointers and function pointers are the same size. Nor does it guarantee that you can use them interchangeably. And even if they're the same size, because of Data Execution Prevention, you should never mix data and code pointers.

Comment: @Filipe I do not understand the Data Execution Prevention part of your comment. From my understanding it does not matter where the pointer is, it only matters where the pointer points to, so putting a function pointer on the stack pointing to a regular function must always work. So I do not see the difference between a void pointer and a function pointer in terms of Data Execution Prevention. Did I miss something?

Comment: @nwp Sure it doesn't matter where the pointer is stored - my comment about DEP was to highlight how bad of an idea it is to mix data and code because of the mysterious bugs it may cause. It may be the case that void pointers and function pointers are indeed the same size and converting between the two is defined (as is the case in POSIX), but as far as the C standard is concerned, this cannot be assumed. There are numerous questions here in SO about this, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c