# Casting between C++ method pointers with identical parameters and compatible return values

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

Suppose you have these classes:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};

class Gen {
public: 
     A* genA(int val);
     B* genB(int val);
     C* genC(int val);
};
```

With these I can do this:

```
Gen g;
A* a = g.genA(1);
A* b = g.genB(1);
A* c = g.genC(1);
```

Now, suppose I want to pass the generating function around to avoid having to build an enum and table or some other layer of indirection. (And also suppose that because didn't write `Gen` I can't just change the return types.) Then I would want something like this typedef:

```
typedef A* (Gen::*GenMethod)(int);
```

Unfortunately you can't directly assign &Gen::genB or &Gen::genC to a pointer of that type, nor can you use a `static_cast<>` to cast it to that type.

You can, however, use a `reinterpret_cast<>`, which isn't surprising because `reinterpret_cast<>` lets you do all sorts of things.

In my testing the code using the `reinterpret_cast<>` for this case works fine. So my questions are:

1. Is there a better/more specific way of doing this (without building a layer of indirection), and
2. If not, is this one of those rare cases where a `reinterpret_cast<>` can be used safely?

Comment: I found a [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782166/function-pointers-with-different-return-types) but can't find one specific to your question.

Comment: It is UB. The compilers are allowed to assume that UB never happens, so a compiler that is able to see through this trick can just delete the cast and surrounding code.

Comment: Yeah, actually different return types would pose a more obvious problem. 

I was expecting `static_cast` to work in this scenario and the fact that it doesn't makes the use of `reinterpret_cast` suspicious. Still, if there's a problem I can't tell where it would come from.

Comment: So the UB explanation predicts that the optimizer will screw things up. Maybe so.

Comment: Are you sure it's UB, though? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118638/15956854 implies things in this area are unspecified rather than undefined,  and the former gets different optimizer treatment than the latter. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995657/is-reinterpret-cast-type-punning-actually-undefined-behavior

Comment: Put them into a `std::function<A*(Gen&,int)> dispatch(&Gen::genB);` and call as `dispatch(g, 1)`.

Comment: `std::function<>` does seem to work well for this!

Comment: @j6t could you write an simple answer form your comment?

Answer (score 6):

You can store these covariant member function pointers in a `std::function`:

```
std::function<A*(Gen&, int)> dispatch(&Gen::genB);
```

and then call it like this:

```
Gen g;
A* b = dispatch(g, 1);
```

This works because the return types of the callables stored in a `std::function` need only be convertible to the type given in the template argument (`A *`), and need not be exactly of that type. In this example, `B *` is convertibel to `A *`.