# Is there such a thing as a generic function pointer in C that can be assigned/cast to a more restrictive prototype?

Tags: c, function-pointers, dynamic-linking

I have the need to dynamically link against a library at run-time and resolve a series of functions using `dlsym`. My first thought was to use an array of function pointers that can be easily iterated through by leveraging a secondary array of `char *` representing the symbol names.

However, the problem with this is that not all of the functions take the same arguments. Is there a way to use a *generic* function pointer in the array, but assign it to a more restrictive function pointer prototype? For example:

If I need to resolve these functions:

```
int (*functionA)(int)
char (*functionB)(char,int)
```

Is it possible to do something like (pseudo-ish .. )

```
void* functionList(...)[2] = {functionA, functionB};
```

Along with

```
char FuncNameA[] = "functionA";
char FuncNameB[] = "functionB";
char *functionNames[2] = {FuncNameA, FuncNameB};
```

For the purpose of looping though the call to `dlsym` for symbol resolution

```
int i = 0;
for(; i<2; i++)
    functionList[i] = dlsym(DL_OPEN_HANDLE, functionNames[i]);
```

Where DL_OPEN_HANDLE would be defined by an earlier call to `dlopen`.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy, I have no idea. If it were possible I figured it would be something like `void* (*func)(void*, ...)` , or similar.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: `void*` is likely to work, but not guaranteed by the C standard. All *object* pointer types can be converted to `void*` and back again without loss of information, but there's no such guarantee for converting function pointer types to `void*`.

Comment: It is a very delicate area.  The POSIX spec was changed relatively recently.  See [0000074: Pointer types problem](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=74) for POSIX's view on the situation.

Comment: Related question: [Why are function pointers and data pointers incompatible in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The C standard guarantees that any object pointer type can be converted to `void*` and back again without loss of information (meaning that the re-converted pointer will compare equal to the original one).

There is a different guarantee for function pointers: Any function pointer can be converted to any other function pointer type and back again without loss of information.

(There is no guarantee regarding conversions between function pointers and object pointers, or more specifically between function pointers and `void*`.  An implementation could, for example, make `void*` 64 bits and function pointers 128 bits.)

You can use, for example, `void(*)(void)` as a generic function pointer type:

```
typedef void (*funcptr)(void);
```

You must convert back to the original pointer type before executing a call to avoid undefined behavior.

On the other hand, you're using `dlsym()`, which returns a `void*`. My understanding is that POSIX guarantees that the `void*` returned by `dlsym()` (if the `name` argument names a function) can be converted to a function pointer, which can be used to call the function. If the *only* functions you care about are those whose addresses are returned by `dlsym()`, then you can use `void*`.

(POSIX previously guaranteed, as an extension to the C standard, that a function pointer can be converted to `void*` and back again. That guarantee was later dropped. Thanks to Jonathan Leffler for pointing this out.)

In any case, using function pointers to store the addresses of functions probably makes for clearer code.

Comment: Sadly, although it used to, it doesn't any more.  Section [2.12.3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12) provided that guarantee up to POSIX 1003.1:2008, but the revision POSIX 1003.1:2013 removed that subsection.  See also [0000074: Pointer Types Problem](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=74) — also mentioned in a comment to the question — for the details.  Frankly, I'm not sure that what we've got now is better than what we had before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: So POSIX still guarantees that a `void*` returned by `dlsym()` can be converted to a function pointer (if the `name` argument names a function), but does not guarantee that an arbitrary function pointer can be converted to `void*` and back again; is that correct?

Comment: AFAICT, yes.  Which is pretty damn weird, but … who said standards had to be rational?

Comment: Good answer. I'll +1 if you put "any function pointer can be converted to any other function pointer type and back again without loss of information" **first**, and only **then** say that there is no guarantee that a function pointer can be converted into a `void *` and back. Remember - answers are "cognition funnels", but some people are in a hurry, skimming, or are just bad at reading, so you want to help move the minds of readers towards the answer as quickly and clearly as possible, and then elaborate after that.

Comment: @KeithThompson Cool, thanks. I was imagining pulling "Any function pointer can be converted to any other function pointer type ..." up to be the very first sentence of the whole answer, and then transitioning into what you said about `void*` with something like "Not to be confused with the similar guarantee about `void*`, which only applies to object pointer types. An implementation could, for example, make `void*` 64 bits and function pointers 128 bits." But this is already an improvement, so +1.

Comment: I'm thinking it would be legal to type pun `union { void *obj; void (*func)(void) }` if you need generics across both data and functions.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably define your list as `void *functionList[2]`, since `dlsym` returns a `void *`.  Once you know which function you have, you can cast it to the proper type.

```
void *functionList[2];

...

int (*functionA)(int) = (int(*)(int))functionList[0];
char (*functionB)(char,int) = (char(*)(char, int))functionList[1];
```

Comment: I guess this is what I thinking, albeit backwards for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`dlsym` returns a data pointer of type `void *`, but POSIX guarantees that this can be cast to a function pointer of the appropriate type:

> Implementations supporting the XSI extension [...] require that an object of type `void *` can hold a pointer to a function. The result of converting a pointer to a function into a pointer to another data type (except `void *`) is still undefined, however.

Since Version 7 of POSIX, all implementations (not just XSI) are required to support the conversion.

Because conversion from a `void *` pointer to a function pointer via a direct cast can result in compiler warnings, older versions of POSIX recommend performing the conversion via aliasing:

```
int (*fptr)(int);
*(void **)(&fptr) = dlsym(handle, "my_function");
```

In the current version the recommendation is changed to:

```
int (*fptr)(int);
fptr = (int (*)(int))dlsym(handle, "my_function");
```

Comment: Geez, that former syntax is ugly. The latter syntax is actually readable; I have no idea how to interpret the former.

Comment: @sherrellbc it's aliasing `fptr` with a `void*` pointer by casting a pointer to `fptr` to a pointer to pointer to void, dereferencing it, and then assigning to the result. As you say, it's ugly; you may see it in even relatively recent code, though.