# Cast integer to function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to cast an integer to a function pointer. Basically my integer value contains the address of the function pointer, so I am trying to cast it into it.

I am trying to do the following-

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(unsigned int arg1);

void function1(unsigned int argument)
{
}

void function2(unsigned int argument, func_ptr argument2)
{
    /* Do something here*/
}

void function3(unsigned int argument)
{
    function2(123,(func_ptr)argument);
}
```

I am calling function3, whose argument contains the address of function1. When I run the program, I get the following warning-

```
cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Is there any way I can deal with this warning?

Comment: You're running on a 64-bit system where an `int` is 4 bytes but a pointer is 8 bytes, right?

Comment: Why not `void function3(func_ptr argument)`? Then `function2(123, argument);`?

Comment: @iBug yes, but I wish to make it system independant

Comment: @David, could you please elaborate I do not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Since you want to call `function2` within `function3` and `function2` takes a `func_ptr` argument, just declare `function3` with a `func_ptr` parameter to pass to `function2`. You do not want to start casting integers to addresses.

Comment: Try `void function3(unsigned long long argument)`

Comment: There is no portable way to do what you want. Don't cast between function pointers and anything else if portability is your goal.

Answer (score 3):

> Cast integer to function pointer
>   "I wish to make it system independant"

This is not 100% possible because C does not specify an integer type that can certainly hold all of the orignal *function pointer*.

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation. C11dr §[6.3.2.3 5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5)

Going the other way:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. **If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined.** The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type. §[6.3.2.3 6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6)

Example: function pointers are 128 bit and the widest integer type is 64 bit.

Code can attempt using the widest integer types like `(u)intmax_t`.  Although that does have a high chance of success, it still may be too small on select platforms.

---

Optional integer types like `(u)intptr_t` can round trip a `void *` *object pointer* though.  A *function pointer* may be wider than a `void *`, so this approach is insufficient for a system independent solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do not get in the habit of trying to cast integer types to pointers. That isn't the proper way to pass the address of something -- that's why there is pointer types. (yes, you can represent a pointer with an unsigned type provided the unsigned type is the same size as a pointer, but don't, instead use a pointer where a pointer is required)

In your example of `function3` you want to call `function2` from within it. Since `function2` requires as a parameter a type `func_ptr`, `function3` should have a parameter of `func_ptr` type in its parameter list so that you can pass it to `function2` within. (unless you have a `func_ptr` defined globally -- but that should be avoided as well unless absolutely required -- such as a callback, not relevant here and rarely seen when learning C)

A short example putting your pieces together may help. This makes use of your function definitions and typedef to provide a proper argument to `function3` which it can utilize in its call to `function2`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*func_ptr)(unsigned int arg1);

void function1(unsigned int argument)
{
    printf ("my dog has %u fleas.\n", argument); 
}

void function2 (unsigned int argument, func_ptr argument2)
{
    printf ("my cat has %u fleas.\n", argument);
    argument2 (argument); 
}

void function3(func_ptr argument)
{
    function2 (123, argument);
}

int main (void) {

    function2 (4, function1);
    function3 (function1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fncptr
my cat has 4 fleas.
my dog has 4 fleas.
my cat has 123 fleas.
my dog has 123 fleas.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard doesn't allow casting even `void *` to a pointer to a function or back again - the wording for `void *` is in [6.3.2.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p1):

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from **a pointer to any object type**. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

However, functions are not objects so you cannot even cast a function pointer to `void *` portably.

Now, it is said that a pointer can be converted to  an integer, and back again, though:

> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. **If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined.** The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

If your (function) pointers are say 64 bits and `int` 32 bits, the behaviour is undefined. For pointers to objects you can use `(u)intptr_t` - but this is not guaranteed to work with function pointers. Instead for function pointers it is guaranteed that you can cast any function pointer to another, so you can use a [generic function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482624/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-generic-function-pointer-in-c-that-can-be-assigned-ca), for example

```
typedef void (*funcptr)(void);
```

and cast this to the proper function-pointer-type before calling.

---

If you need an integer too, then you must use an union

```
union int_or_funcptr {
    int integer;
    funcptr function;
}
```

and if the function is needed, assign or read the `function` member of the union, casting it properly prior to calling it.