# using a trampoline with one function as an argument

Tags: c, pointers, trampolines

I know what a trampoline function is, but I've been having trouble avoiding stack overflow using trampolines. So far, the only method I can think of is to use global variables, which are discouraged and can complicate programs.

The trampoline function I want to use is shown below.

```
void trampoline(void *(*fun)()) {
  while (fun != NULL) {
    void *callback = fun();
    fun = (void *(*)())callback;
  }
}
```

When I try to pass in functions with parameters, such as those in the code fragment below, I end up creating stacks, which is not what I want. I was wondering if there was a way to use my trampoline function without using global variables or passing in any extra arguments?

```
void *f1();
void *f2();

void *f1(int *n) {
  if (*n == 0) {
    return NULL;
  } else {
    return f2(n);
  }
}

void *f2(int *n) {
  --*n;
  return f1(n);
}

int main() {
  int a = 1000000;
  trampoline(f1(&a));
  return 0;
}
```

The program below behaves how I want it to, but it uses a global variable, which is widely discouraged.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 1000;

void trampoline(void *(*f)()) {
  while (f) {
    void *g = f();
    f = (void *(*)())g;
  }
}

void *f1();
void *f2();

void *f1() {
  if (a == 0) {
    return NULL;
  } else {
    return f2;
  }
}

void *f2() {
  --a;
  return f1;
}

int main() {

  trampoline(f1);
  return 0;
}
```

> Clarification: I do not want to modify the trampoline function above, but I want reduced stack creation.

Comment: probably you mean _if (\*n == 0)_ if *f1*

Comment: @bruno thanks for catching the typo

Comment: Strictly speaking, C doesn't guarantee that a `void *` can hold a function pointer, only a data pointer.

Comment: but @TomKarzes the parameter syntax specifies that a trampoline must take in a void function pointer, right?

Comment: @gt453 A void function pointer is not the same as a void pointer.  In practice, you're almost certainly safe, but strictly speaking function pointers can have different sizes from data pointers.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482624/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-generic-function-pointer-in-c-that-can-be-assigned-ca) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First probably you mean

```
void *f1(int *n) {
  if (*n == 0) {  /* <<< */
    return NULL;
  } else {
    return f2(n);
  }
}
```

rather than

```
void *f1(int *n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return NULL;
  } else {
    return f2(n);
  }
}
```

Compiling with optimization the compiler will detect the final recursion in both function and the used size of the stack will be constant and not linked with *a*.

In fact like that for the compiler you *main* just does *return 0;* ;-)

To *hope* the calls you can do

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int a = argc * 1000000;
  trampoline(f1(&a));
  return a;
}
```

---

With your second definition after your edit the compiler cannot optimize replacing all by the right *return*

On my PI4 *gcc* 8.3.0 with the option -O detects the final recursions and the program just uses time to finish, but without a stack overflow

---

Note *gcc* as a special management for the trampoline case, with the dedicated option "-Wtrampoline"

Comment: @gt453 I think this is a false problem because all compilers detect final recursions since long time, are you using a diplodocus compiling for 8080 ?

Comment: @gt453 I run on a PI4 (raspbian) and your new version just taken time to finish well

Comment: Yes, but can you find a version that works like my new version but doesn't use global variables? Global variables can create hidden dependencies b/w different parts of a program, but they are still manageable as long as I make the right function calls. Is there any way to avoid stack frame creation using the given trampoline function that doesn't involve using global variables?

Comment: @gt453 please stop to delete your question, each time I loose the edition of my answer and I have to redo all, this is very stressing

Comment: okay, but I still don't know how to resolve my actual question.

Comment: @gt453 while the compiler can manage a terminal call it does, your global variable just limit the optimization the compiler was able to do, and to not remoave allall

Comment: so @bruno how can I maximize optimization and avoid the creation of stack frames and use the given trampoline function? When I run your solution, my program still creates stack frames.

Comment: @gt453 that depends on the compiler, _gcc_ has a special management about the trampoline and even the dedicated option "-Wtrampoline". What is your compiler ?

Comment: @gt453 with at least -O ?

Comment: @gt453 to produce *prog_name* rather than *a.out* use "-o prog_name" (lower case 'o'), to optimize use "-O" (upper case 'O'), so to have both "gcc -o prog_name -O prog_name.c"

Comment: @gt453 ask the people implementing _gcc_ ;-) More seriously, all is about the generated code, while the norm of C does not impose to always manage the terminal recursion whatever the optimize level you cannot 'blame' _gcc_ to request at least "-O" to do. Frankly the optimizations done by (at least) _gcc_ are awesome, I can only congratulate them

Comment: @gt453 finally is my answer useful for you ?