# Why do I need to avoid "casting a function pointer to a generic pointer" in this case?

Tags: c, function-pointers, void-pointers

assume that I have a struct that has a function pointer as a member:

```
struct Class
{
    void (*function)();
}
```

I then want to assign a function to this member. I wanted to do this:

```
typedef void (*func_pointer)();
func_pointer method = va_arg(arg_list, func_pointer);
struct Class foo;
```

since the type of both `foo.function` and `method` are `void (*)()` (a "generic" function pointer) I assume that I can just equate them together, something like `foo.function = method`.

However, the book I'm reading mentioned that ANSI C "does not let us" cast between "void *" and a "function pointer". ([Object Oriented Programming with ANSI C, chapter 6, page 64](https://www.cs.rit.edu/%7Eats/books/ooc.pdf)) Therefore they did something like this:

```
*(func_ptr*) &foo.function = method;
```

Why though? why is it necessary? I do not see any `void *` pointer here. Why can't I just copy the value of `method` to `foo.function`?

Since the code in the book is fairly involved I tried to simplify it but that may have changed the context, here's the real code: (full code is in a [git repo](https://github.com/shichao-an/ooc/tree/master/06) if you wanted to take a look, file Object.c.)

```
struct Class
{
    const struct Object _;
    const char * name;
    const struct Class * super;
    size_t size;
    void * (*ctor)(const void * self, va_list * arg_ptr);
    void * (*dtor)(const void * self);
    int (*differ)(const void * self, const void * other);
    int (*puto)(const void * self, FILE * file_ptr);
};
```

```
{
        typedef void (*voidf) (); /* generic function pointer */
        voidf selector;
        va_list ap = *app;
        while ((selector = va_arg(ap, voidf)))
        {
            voidf method = va_arg(ap, voidf);
            if (selector == (voidf) ctor)
                *(voidf *) &self — > ctor = method;
            else if (selector == (voidf) dtor)
                *(voidf *) &self — > dtor = method;
            else if (selector == (voidf) differ)
                *(voidf *) &self — > differ = method;
            else if (selector == (voidf) puto)
                *(voidf *) &self — > puto = method;
        }
        return self;
    }
```

In this case my thinking would be that it is sufficient to just do a `self->ctor = method` and call it a day.

Comment: You're right, that doesn't make any sense. What's the book, page number, etc?  Can you include more context?

Comment: *casting between "void *" and a "function pointer" is illegal.* this is true, but you don't have a `void*` in your code. You have 2 `void (*)()`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I've included the book and page number in a new edit.

Comment: @stanle: That new code does not compile and has too many errors to correct reasonably.

Comment: @EricPostpischil here's a [git repo](https://github.com/shichao-an/ooc/tree/master/06) of the full code (file Object.c) . I've compiled and ran it successfully. Just wanted to know why it was done that way.

Comment: There is no "generic function pointer" - `void (*)()` is pointer to function taking unspecified arguments and returning `void`

Comment: @M.M I know that, which is why I put a quote-on-quote "generic", just using `void (*) ()` as a representative to them all. I think it works because all function pointers types can be freely casted to one another, as long as you don't call them under the wrong cast.

Comment: See also [Why can't I cast a function pointer to (void *)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36645660/3422102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem with your code, and there's also no problem with that passage in the book. The "problem" is that the passage doesn't apply to your code.

> the book I'm reading mentioned that casting between "void *" and a "function pointer" is illegal.

This is true. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c).

But in your code you don't have a `void*`. `foo.function` is a `void(*)()` (a pointer to a function taking any number of arguments and returning `void`), which is the same type as `func_pointer`. So there's no need to do any sort of casting. `foo.function = method;` is correct.

**Edit**

From the clarifications you've added to your question, it seems like the book is saying something along the lines of: "With a `void*` we'd be able to avoid a lot of ugly casts between types, but since ANSI C doesn't allow `void*` to hold function pointers we can't avoid these casts."

Simplifying one of the examples from the book:

```
struct Class {
    void * (*ctor)(const void * self, va_list * arg_ptr);
};
struct Class self;

typedef void (*voidf)();
voidf method = ...;

*(voidf*)&self.ctor = method;
```

That cast is necessary because `self.ctor` is a `void* (*)(const void*, va_list*)`, not a `void(*)()`.

If you *could* use a `void*` here, you could instead do:

```
void *method = ...;
self.ctor = method;
```

Without doing any casts.

Comment: But there are no data pointers in the question.

Comment: 2. Do not link the answers (which can be wrong) only cite the C standard

Comment: @0___________ I know, that's exactly what I'm saying: *But in your code you don't have a `void*`*

Comment: It is not true that casting between `void *` and a pointer to a function type is illegal. The C standard omits any definition of the behavior, but it does not prohibit the conversion. The constraints of the cast operator (C 2018 6.5.4 2-4) allow it.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, I've updated the question with the full link to the book and some code excerpts, let me know if you still believe that I'm correct in this case!

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've updated the question with the actual quote from the book to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

I would not hide any pointers behind typedefs (even function pointers). It makes code difficult to read and error-prone.

```
typedef void func();

struct Class
{
    func *fptr;
};

struct Class bar(int x, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    func *fp;
    struct Class c;

    va_start(va, x);
    fp = va_arg(va, func *);
    c.fptr = fp;

    return c;
}
```

You do not need any casts.